# Capture a screenshot by keyboard shortcut?

Tags: screenshot

`scrot` works on my RPi-3 to take screenshots. However, the terminal window to run `scrot` will also be included in the screenshot. I understand I can use delay and minimise the terminal window, but it is still in the top bar. Now I'm wondering whether it is possible to register the command `scrot` to a keyboard shortcut to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing the Print screen button will save a PNG screenshot in your home folder (/home/pi). No need for custom key mapping.